# SQL query to join 4 Tables and get sum of 2 columns from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, casting

## **Table 1: Purchase Report**

```
|id| VoucherNO| VoucherDate|
+--+----------+------------+
|1 |  0001    |  28/9/2017 |
|2 |  0010    |  27/9/2017 |
```

## **Table 2: Detail Purchase Report**

```
|id | ITEMID | QTYpurchased | voucher
+---+--------+--------------+--------
|1  |   101  | 12           |   0001
|2  |   120  | 25           |   0001
|3  |   121  | 21           |   0014
```

## **Table 3: Sale Report**

```
|id| VoucherNO| VoucherDate|
+--+----------+------------+
|1 |  0025    |  25/9/2017 |
|2 |  0058    |  23/9/2017 |
```

## **Table 4: Detail Sale**

```
|id | ITEMID | QTYpurchased | voucher
+---+--------+--------------+--------
|1  |  101   |  8           |   0025
|2  |  120   |  5           |   0025
|3  |  121   | 10           |   0058
```

Objective of the query is to join all 4 Tables to return 2 Columns
ie.,

- Column 1 : Item Name
- 2 : Difference Purchased qty and sold qty having same item id
  in between given dates gives the qty of a item at that particular date.

Query I tried is as follows

```
SELECT
  A.ITEMN, 
  A.ITEMNAME,
  SUM(CAST(C.QUANTITY AS numeric(18,2))) - SUM(CAST(A.QTY AS numeric(18,2))) as QTY 
FROM DETAILSALE A, SALESREPORT B, DETAILPURCHASES C, PURCHASEREPORT D 
WHERE A.BARCODE = B.VOUCHERNO 
  AND  C.BARCODE = D.VOUCHERNO 
  AND D.VOUCHERDATE=B.VOUCHERDATE
  AND D.VOUCHERDATE BETWEEN '" & DATE1.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "'   
GROUP BY A.ITEMN,A.ITEMNAME 
ORDER BY A.ITEMN ASC
```

## Required Output:

```
| ITEMID | QTY |
+--------+-----+
|  101   | 2   |
|  120   | 10  |
|  121   | 10  |
```

Comment: you have included the example data, but it would help if you also included the example output.

Comment: @JonScott I have added Sample output above. Please have a look into it

Comment: 1) You should have told us why you are not satisfied with your query. Wrong sums? 2) You are using a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992. I have no idea why you are using it instead of proper joins. Are you learning from a book from the 1980s? 3) When using alias names, use readable mnemonic ones, e.g. `ds` for `detailsale`, `s` for `sale`, not `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Alias names are meant to help readability not decrease it.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are interested in a single date or in a date range. And please elaborate how you get from your sample data to the desired result. For item 121 I see 21 purchased, 10 sold, result 10. I would have expected 11 = 21 - 10.

Comment: Sorry for bit low grade coding. Just looking into a example from old book as you said. But I got my solution for it using joins.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Tables 3&4 should NOT be a table but should be achieved through a query. Table 3 looks to be the same as Table 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate first and only join then. I am missing a product table from your description and names in your table descriptions and query don't match, so you may have to adjust names in my query:

```
select
  product.id,
  product.name,
  purchases.total,
  sales.total
from product
left join
(
  select itemid, sum(quantity) as total
  from detail_purchase
  where voucher in (select voucher from purchase where date between date '2017-09-01' 
                                                                and date '2017-09-05')
  group by itemid
) purchases on purchases.itemid = product.itemid
left join
(
  select itemid, sum(quantity) as total
  from detail_sale
  where voucher in (select voucher from sale where date between date '2017-09-01'
                                                            and date '2017-09-05')
  group by itemid
) sales on sales.itemid = product.itemid;
```

Change outer joins to inner joins, if you only want products that where bought and/or sold.